# linux centos 7 - create delete accounts

Tags: linux, vmware, centos-7

I am running centos 7 as virtual machine through vmware, the default user was:

```
unsername: osboxes.org
password:  osboxes.org
```

I created new user (john), then removed osboxes.org along its home directory using the `-r` flag as described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-a-centos-7-server)

Now I am logged in as john, but I can still see osboxes in the terminal:

```
[john@osboxes ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'osboxes' is the hostname of your (virtual) machine. Change it like [explained here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/centos-hostname-change).

You should not ask two completely different questions in one post.

Comment: So it is called "hostname"! :) Thank you so much, I'll read some stuff about it!